# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application for _imaging module

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, python-imaging-library

I am trying to extract features from an image using Grey Level Co-occurrence Matrix in Python 2.7.9 
I found the code given below in some other answer. When I run this code I get:

> ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed.

Then I installed PIL module and when I try to import its `_imaging` package, it gives another piece of error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I have already researched a lot on the internet but no solution given really seems to work, like uninstalling PIL and installing PILLOW and checking the compatibility of the version of python and the modules.

```
import skimage.io
import skimage.feature

im = skimage.io.imread('python.jpg', as_grey=True)

im = skimage.img_as_ubyte(im)
im /= 32

g = skimage.feature.greycomatrix(im, [1], [0], levels=8, symmetric=False, normed=True)

print skimage.feature.greycoprops(g, 'contrast')[0][0]
print skimage.feature.greycoprops(g, 'energy')[0][0]
print skimage.feature.greycoprops(g, 'homogeneity')[0][0]
print skimage.feature.greycoprops(g, 'correlation')[0][0]
```

Comment: My guess is, you've mixed a 64-bit python interpreter with a 32-bit python module.

Comment: Thanku @Sneftel. I got the wrong module. Now when I installed a new one, it worked.

Comment: One of you can post an answer to indicate that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing a 64 bit PILLOW module Pillow‑2.8.2‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)