# import skimage not a Valid Win32 application python3

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, anaconda, scikit-image

I'm trying to run [this file](https://github.com/tensorlayer/tensorlayer/blob/master/examples/pretrained_cnn/tutorial_vgg19.py) which requires skimage. So, I installed scikit-image using `pip install scikit-image`. But when I run the file, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Studies/07) IISC/Academics/1st Sem/E9 241 - Digital Image Processing/Assignments/FinalProject/Codes/tensorlayer/tensorlayer/examples/pretrained_cnn/tutorial_vgg19.py", line 18, in <module>
    import skimage
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py", line 167, in <module>
    from .util.dtype import (img_as_float32,
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._montage import montage, montage2d
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\_montage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .. import exposure
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .exposure import histogram, equalize_hist, \
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\exposure.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..color import rgb2gray
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .colorconv import (convert_colorspace,
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 369, in <module>
    rgb_from_xyz = linalg.inv(xyz_from_rgb)
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 946, in inv
    a1 = _asarray_validated(a, check_finite=check_finite)
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py", line 228, in _asarray_validated
    import scipy.sparse
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 229, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "D:\Workspaces\Anaconda\envs\dip_project\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I searched on google as well as on StackOverflow. Many answers suggested to download and install 64-bit version of scikit-image. I tried that, with no luck. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30996566/3337089) answer suggested to install 64-bit version of Pillow. I tried that, with no luck.

I'm using python 3.7 on a 64-bit windows 8.1. I'm using python inside a virtual env created by Anaconda3.
So, I even tried `conda install scikit-image`. This upgraded my `numpy` and a whole lot of others, but didn't solve the issue. Instead, after doing this step, i wasn't even able to import `numpy`, `cv2` and others. `conda remove scikit-image` got me back to previous state. I have even tried creating a whole new conda environment, but same issue.

I'm completely stuck here with no idea about how to proceed. Please help!!!

Comment: Do you have all these installed? (check with `pip list --local`)
numpy>=1.11
scipy>=0.17.0
matplotlib>=2.0.0,!=3.0.0
networkx>=2.0
pillow>=4.3.0
imageio>=2.0.1
PyWavelets>=0.4.0
dask[array]>=0.9.0
cloudpickle>=0.2.1

Comment: I've numpy-1.15.4, scipy=1.1.0, networkx=2.2, Pillow=5.3.0, PyWavelets=1.0.1, dask=0.20.0, cloudpickle=0.6.1. So, I don't have matplotlib and imageio. I'll try to install them using pip and check again.

Comment: Installed matplotlib=3.0.1 and imageio=2.4.1. No success. Same error

Comment: It explicitly says no matplotlib 3, so maybe that's a problem?

Comment: Oh! So, which version do you suggest me to use for matplotlib?

Comment: I tired installing `matplotlib=2.2.3` using `conda`. This upgraded `numpy` to `1.15.4`. Now even `import numpy` fails.

Comment: Something seems fundamentally broken. I would everything that has to do with python or conda and then try again from scratch. I think I installed it via Anaconda Navigator (windows 10) and ran into no problems

Comment: Okay. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: You can try to downgrade pillow to 4.x. I had DLL issues with 5.x versions. I may downgrade some other libraries. Also, I am not sure pillow has support for Python 3.7. Did you try with Python 3.6?

Comment: No, I didn't try with Python 3.6. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: It worked! Trying with python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python 3.6 resolved this error, I have no idea how or why!
I followed the below steps and is working fine

```
conda create -n test01 python=3.6
conda install scikit-image
```

Another thing which I'm not sure matters or not is that I was launching spyder from anaconda prompt. But it turned out spyder was not installed in the env 'test01'. So, when I opened Anaconda Navigator, there was an option to install spyder. I installed spyder again and opened spyder there and it worked.